# Moment JS setting TimeZone to EST - alloy/moment

Tags: date, momentjs, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I am using momentjs in alloy framework in Appcelerator. My api returns the date as - `2017-09-06T12:03:00.000Z` I am using below code to format this date into readable form -

```
var dt =  moment(record.createddate);
$.dateValue.text = moment(dt).format('lll');
```

But the output I get is - `Sep 6, 2017 5:33 PM`, which is not correct as the date saved in db and returned from api is EST and the date getting displayed is `GMT+0530`. How should i format this date so that I get the correct date value?

Comment: Shouldn't `moment('2017-09-06T12:03:00.000Z').format('lll')` return `Sep 6, 2017 2:03 PM` instead of `Sep 6, 2017 5:33 PM` ?

Comment: Exactly it should and that is what I am expecting, but it returns `Sep 6, 2017 5:33 PM`. :(

Answer (score 3):

I guess, somewhere in your code, the `moment`'s default timezone is set to GMT+0530. Something like `moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Colombo')` could do this.

You can define in what timezone you want to display your date. This should work for you :

```
moment('2017-09-06T12:03:00.000Z').tz("Etc/GMT").format('lll')
```

Or if you want the value I suggested in the comments :

```
moment('2017-09-06T12:03:00.000Z').tz("Etc/GMT-2").format('lll')
```

For more informations about moment.js timezones, you can check [the moment.js timezone docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Hope this helps !

Comment: Yes that could have been an easier fix but the problem is alloy framework doesn't have MomentTimezone, but only Moment. I mean this part `.tz("Etc/GMT").format('lll')` is not possible in Alloy.